# Ubuntu 16.04 - System settings - Printers and Software & Updates not working

Tags: unity, printing

After upgrading from 14 just these two icons do not do anything. All other icons are functioning properly.

I have reinstalled ubuntu-desktop as well as system-config-printer-gnome and unity-control-center, but that did not help. My most acute problem is that I cannot find a way to set up my network printer.

Any clues?

Comment: Is hplip setup?

Comment: Thanks, George for the hint. Hplip was not installed. Unfortunately, the two system icons (printers and software & updates) are still dead and when I try to print in gedit, the only option I get is 'printing to file'.

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue yesterday (on a fresh install of ubuntu studio) 
and found (by checking syslog) it was stuck trying to use ip6 to talk to the upstream mirror.
(like most people on dsl here in AU I only have ip4 connectivity to the outside world at home)

"these two icons do not do anything"

if you mean "software" and "software updater"

thats how it looked to me (clicked and nothing happened) 
so thinking you might be seeing a similar problem.

If your connection only does ip4 and the upstream mirror only does ip6
you probably only need to choose a different mirror (one that talks ip4) 
to get it working.

software updates are now working here (changed the mirror setting - so unless there was an outage thinking thats probably what fixed it)

Comment: Thanks, Michael. The two icons that seem dead are 'Printers' and 'Software & Updates. I will have a look at my syslog. Re. the first one, my 'cups' seems to be working normally. Re. the first one, when I install the Gome apt updater manually my system generates a System Program Error, so something must have gone wrong in the release upgrade.